# CSS Div side-by-side without set width

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to get two divs to appear side by side as follows:

- First div is displayed on the left `float: left` and takes up as much space as it needs.
- Second div appears on the right `float: right` and takes the remaining space.

The issue is that I do not have a set `width` for any of those divs so they just take up as much space as they can: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzREv/1/)

I have found several solutions but all of them required setting width for one of the divs which is what I'm trying to avoid. Any possible solution?

Comment: what happens if the left DIV fills the entire screen width? Wouldn't the right DIV drop?

Comment: @tcoder: That would be a problem indeed. To be honest the left div should never take up more than 60% of the screen, but I will probably have to play around with `min-width` on the right div and just stretch the page if really needed... But it should never really happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#left, #right { display: table-cell; }​
#left { white-space: nowrap; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/LzREv/5/